# WSO2 ESB Custom Message Processor example

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm planning to create a custom message processor to pick up messages from message store. However I haven't find any examples how to create a custom class. Documentation under this topic is very limited.(http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Custom+Message+Processor). Can somebody provide example to create custom message processor ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [MessageProcessor](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v4/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/processor/MessageProcessor.java) interface - and the implementations and other classes [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v4/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/processor/). Once you have your processor setup, you can place your jars in the lib folder. Then follow the instructions in the link you posted in the OP.

Comment: Thanks I used SamplingProcessor as a base and that did the trick.